# Javascript Ternary question about Codecademy's high-order functions exercises

Tags: javascript, ternary

I am going through Codecademy's Into to JS course and I stumbled on a problem. https://www.codecademy.com/courses/introduction-to-javascript/lessons/higher-order-functions/exercises/review for reference.

I can't understand why the function containing the ternary returns "undefined", while the function containing the "if-else" statement works.

```js
const addTwo = num => {
  return num + 2;
}

const checkConsistentOutput = (func, val) => {
  const checkA = val + 2
  const checkB = func(val)
  if (checkA === checkB) {
    return func(val)
  } else {
    return "inconsistent results"
  }
}

console.log(checkConsistentOutput(addTwo, 5));
```

VS

```js
const addTwo = num => {
  return num + 2;
}

const checkConsistentOutput = (func, val) => {
  const checkA = val + 2
  const checkB = func(val)
  checkA === checkB ? func(val) : "inconsistent results"
}

console.log(checkConsistentOutput(addTwo, 5));
```

What am I missing and how should I write the ternary statement in order to make it work?

Comment: You need a `return` statement: `return checkA === checkB ? func(val) : "inconsistent results";`

Comment: the working version has a `return` statement and the non-working one doesn't. Any function without a `return` statement (or more generally one that doesn't reach a `return` statement while executing) will automatically return `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't believe I was missing something so simple...